# Selenium click thank you very much

Tags: selenium

[image]

1. How to locate clicks?
2. unable to locate, click no response
   I can view my screenshot, the "spot item list" is the location that needs to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

@xupeng, Try with this format-

```
"//div[contains(text(),'the text between the tags')]"
```